# Бесконечный цикл для индекса типа std::size_t

Tags: c++, циклы, for

Почему не работает цикл вида:

```
for (size_t i = str.length(); i>=0; --i)
```

Разве тип возвращаемого значения у length не size_t? Почему цикл выдает ошибку?

Comment: Добавьте код в сам вопрос

Comment: "Разве тип возвращаемого значения у length не size_t?" - откуда возникли эти сомнения? Что такое "цикл выдает ошибку"? Какую ошибку? Когда?

Answer (score 12):

`size_t` - тип обычно беззнаковый. А беззнаковое число **всегда** `>=0`.

Даже если уменьшить *беззнаковый* нуль на 1. Что получим? `-1`? Нет, поскольку `-` с беззнаковым числом смысла не имеет. Так что получим мы (описанный в стандарте) переход к числу `0xFF..FF`, и цикл продолжается...

Кстати, учтите, что для `i = str.length()` обращение `str[i]` означает выход за границы диапазона и UB.

Comment: Не известно что в цикле, может он не обращается к  str[i]

Comment: @ARHovsepyan А я что, написал, что у него ошибка? я так, ненавязчиво напомнил :)

Comment: а я что, написал, что вы ошиблись?  Я так  намекнул на отсутствие кода...

Answer (score 8):

### Условие завершения цикла никогда не выполнится.

Цикл не может выдать ошибку. Но он у вас бесконечный, так как число типа `size_t` не может быть отрицательным, и условие `i >= 0` выполняется всегда. Кроме того у вас выход за пределы индекса для `str`.

Варианты исправления:

Первый (воспользоваться счётчиком типа `int`):

```
for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
```

Второй (цикл в другую сторону):

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно и так:

```
size_t i = str.length(); 
while(i--) {
   '''
}
```

Меньше символов,  сравнение на равенство с нулем проще, нет преобразований

Comment: Тогда уж `i = str.length()+1`, раз клиент хочет начинать с `str.length()`. Или `do { ... } while(i--);`

Comment: Я не знаю чего хочет клиент, но если  клиент использует  i == str.length()  только для какого то условия , то да, вы правы,

Answer (score 4):

Корректными идиомами для реализации обратной итерации с беззнаковым индексом, учитывающими природу беззнакового типа, являются

```
for (size_t i = str.length(); i-- > 0; ) 
{
  // Работаем с `str[i]`
}

for (size_t i = str.length(); i > 0; ) 
{
  --i;
  // Работаем с `str[i]`
}

for (size_t i = str.length() - 1; i != -1; --i) 
{
  // Работаем с `str[i]`
}
```

Выбирайте, какой вариант вам больше нравится.

Стоит также заметить, что все эти варианты работоспособны независимо от знаковости используемого типа.

Эти варианты начинают доступ с `str[str.length() - 1]` и идут вниз до `0`. У вас доступ начинается с `str[str.length()]`. Умышленно ли, по ошибке ли - сказать невозможно.

Comment: В первом цикле `--i>0`, наверное, `i-->0`?

Comment: @Harry: Да, верно. Исправил. Спасибо!

Comment: А красиво выглядит - `i-->0` - ну прям как в математике. Так семантично... :)