# С++ файловый ввод/вывод. как считывать строку вместе с пробелами в конце?

Tags: c++

пишу

```
getline(myfile, inner);

        for (int i=0; inner[i]==' '; i++)
          startSpace++;
        for (int i=inner.size(); inner[i]==' '; i--)
          endSpace++;
```

но в `endSpace` всегда лежит 0, даже если в файле после этой строки были пробелы. чем можно скушать строку из файла вместе со всеми пробелами?

Comment: `int i=inner.size();` - это вообще-то выход за пределы строки...  Что вы вообще хотите? В `inner` у вас попадает строка, которая (по умолчанию) завершается `\n`.

Comment: @Harry ошибок нет, компилируется и исполняется, но в чём ошибка понял. спасибо) в endSpace всегда 0 ибо он сразу же видит не пробел, а символ перехода на новую строку похоже. потому и не гонит цикл дальше.

Comment: @Harry: Откуда там может взяться `\n`? `std::getline` читает `\n`, но не заносит его в результат.

Comment: Где объявления переменных? Что такое `inner`? Что такое `startSpace` и `endSpace`? Чему равны их начальные значения?

Comment: Ну и зачем вообше нужен какой то цикл?  getline(myfile, inner); читает  всю строку вместе со всеми пробелами и другими символами

Comment: @AnT Мда не так высказался. Я имел в виду, что понятие считываемой строки - завершение `\n`, а не пробелами (о которых ТС говорил, что они не читаются, т.е. что строка ими завершается). Ну что `\n` - разделитель строк, а не пробел (каковой, впрочем, можно таковым сделать).

Answer (score 2):

в `endSpace` всегда 0 ибо он сразу же видит не пробел, а символ '\0' строку похоже. потому и не гонит цикл дальше

```
for (int i=inner.size()-1; inner[i]==' '; i--)
          endSpace++;
```

это решило проблему

Answer (score 2):

(В предположении, что `inner` - это `std::string`.)

Во-первых, ваш второй цикл начинает итерирование с `i = inner.size()`. Символ `inner[i]` - это всегда символ `\0`. Поэтому ваш второй цикл не делает никаких итераций вообще. Итерирование во втором цикле нужно начинать с `inner.size() - 1`, лучше всего одним из методов [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/923842/%D0%91%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0-stdsize-t/923920#923920) и с использованием беззнакового типа `std::string::size_type`.

Во-вторых, а что произойдет с вашим вторым циклом, если входная строка целиком состоит из пробелов? Не забывайте проверять индексы циклов на выход за пределы строки. Я не знаю, что за ответ должен выдать ваша проверка на такую строку, но наверное нет смысла итерировать вторым циклом вообще, если первый цикл прошел всю строку.

Comment: Эффективнее второй цикл обернуть в if, а не проверять в нём индекс. Ведь первый всегда завершится из-за `'\0'`